# Numba performance for diffusion kernel in double and single precision

Tags: python, numba

I am having trouble in bringing my numba code to high performance. The equivalent code in C++ or Julia executes in ~80 ms for double precision and ~40 ms for single precision on my machine, yet the `numba` code delivers:

**Double precision:**

`In [2]: %timeit diff(at, a, float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), itot, jtot, ktot) 291 ms ± 5.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

**Single precision:**

`In [2]: %timeit diff(at, a, float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), itot, jtot, ktot) 330 ms ± 3.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Numba is not capturing the types correctly, even though each input variable has a clear type. Why is this code more than 3 times slower than C++, and why is single precision not working well?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def diff(at, a, visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi, itot, jtot, ktot):
    for k in range(1, ktot-1):
        for j in range(1, jtot-1):
            for i in range(1, itot-1):
                at[k, j, i] += visc * ( 
                        + ( (a[k+1, j  , i  ] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k-1, j  , i  ]) ) * dxidxi
                        + ( (a[k  , j+1, i  ] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k  , j-1, i  ]) ) * dyidyi
                        + ( (a[k  , j  , i+1] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k  , j  , i-1]) ) * dzidzi )

float_type = np.float32
# float_type = np.float64

itot = 384;
jtot = 384;
ktot = 384;
ncells = itot*jtot*ktot;

at = np.zeros((ktot, jtot, itot), dtype=float_type)

a = np.random.rand(ktot, jtot, itot)
a = a.astype(float_type)

diff(at, a, float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), float_type(0.1), itot, jtot, ktot)
```

For comparison, this is the corresponding Julia code:

```
## Packages
using BenchmarkTools
using LoopVectorization

## Diffusion kernel
function diff!(
        at, a,
        visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi,
        itot, jtot, ktot)

    @tturbo unroll=8 for k in 2:ktot-1
        for j in 2:jtot-1
            for i in 2:itot-1
                at[i, j, k] += visc * (
                    ( (a[i+1, j  , k  ] - a[i, j, k]) - (a[i, j, k] - a[i-1, j  , k  ]) ) * dxidxi +
                    ( (a[i  , j+1, k  ] - a[i, j, k]) - (a[i, j, k] - a[i  , j-1, k  ]) ) * dyidyi +
                    ( (a[i  , j  , k+1] - a[i, j, k]) - (a[i, j, k] - a[i  , j  , k-1]) ) * dzidzi )
            end
        end
    end
end

## Set the grid size.
itot = 384
jtot = 384
ktot = 384

## Solve the problem in double precision.
visc = 0.1
dxidxi = 0.1
dyidyi = 0.1
dzidzi = 0.1

a = rand(Float64, (itot, jtot, ktot))
at = zeros(Float64, (itot, jtot, ktot))

@btime diff!(
        $at, $a,
        $visc, $dxidxi, $dyidyi, $dzidzi,
        $itot, $jtot, $ktot)

## Solve the problem in single precision.
visc_f = Float32(visc)
dxidxi_f = Float32(dxidxi)
dyidyi_f = Float32(dyidyi)
dzidzi_f = Float32(dzidzi)

a_f = rand(Float32, (itot, jtot, ktot))
at_f = zeros(Float32, (itot, jtot, ktot))

@btime diff!(
        $at_f, $a_f,
        $visc_f, $dxidxi_f, $dyidyi_f, $dzidzi_f,
        $itot, $jtot, $ktot)
```

Comment: Can you share the C++ and Julia code which was used for comparison?

Comment: @max9111 I added the Julia code, the C++ is too extensive, but has identical performance as the Julia code. Note that for comparison, I run the julia code on a single thread.

Comment: @max9111. I'd be happy to see your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoiding wrap-around checking

Numba tries to behave the same as Python. Some of this features can be easily turned off, eg. the division by zero checking with `error_model="numpy"`, but I don't know how to turn off wrap-around checking.

Another issue in this example is the float32/64 behavior. You can check the detected signature with `func.nopython_signatures`. Alternatively you can use explicit signatures.

**Workaround 1**

One possibility is to make it obvious to Numba that negative indices are not occurring.

```
@nb.njit(["(float32[:,:,::1])(float32[:,:,::1], float32[:,:,::1], float32, float32, float32, float32)",
          "(float64[:,:,::1])(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64, float64, float64, float64)"])
def diff_2(at, a, visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi):
    ktot, jtot, itot=at.shape
    for k in range(ktot-2):
        for j in range(jtot-2):
            for i in range(itot-2):
                at[k+1, j+1, i+1] += visc * ( 
                        + ( (a[k+2, j+1, i+1] - a[k+1, j+1 , i+1])  
                          - (a[k+1, j+1, i+1] - a[k  , j+1 , i+1]) ) * dxidxi
                        + ( (a[k+1, j+2, i+1] - a[k+1, j+1 , i+1])  
                          - (a[k+1, j+1, i+1] - a[k+1, j   , i+1]) ) * dyidyi
                        + ( (a[k+1, j+1, i+2] - a[k+1, j+1 , i+1])  
                          - (a[k+1, j+1, i+1] - a[k+1, j+1 , i  ]) ) * dzidzi )
    return at

#float32
#%timeit diff_2(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
#31 ms ± 708 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#float64
#%timeit diff_2(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
#65.4 ms ± 805 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Workaround 2**

```
@nb.njit(["(float32[:,:,::1])(float32[:,:,::1], float32[:,:,::1], float32, float32, float32, float32)",
          "(float64[:,:,::1])(float64[:,:,::1], float64[:,:,::1], float64, float64, float64, float64)"],)
def diff_2(at, a, visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi):
    ktot, jtot, itot=at.shape

    for kk in range(ktot-2):
        for jj in range(jtot-2):
            for ii in range(itot-2):
                i=ii+1
                j=jj+1
                k=kk+1

                at[k, j, i] += visc * ( 
                        + ( (a[k+1, j  , i  ] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k-1, j  , i  ]) ) * dxidxi
                        + ( (a[k  , j+1, i  ] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k  , j-1, i  ]) ) * dyidyi
                        + ( (a[k  , j  , i+1] - a[k  , j  , i  ])  
                          - (a[k  , j  , i  ] - a[k  , j  , i-1]) ) * dzidzi )
    return at
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution results in different indexing for `at` and `a`, which is unfortunately not an acceptable solution for code clarity. It is fast though, I hope there is a way to achieve your performance with the original indexing.

Comment: @Chiel I asked a related question on Numba discourse. https://numba.discourse.group/t/how-to-turn-off-wraparound/1607?u=max9111

Comment: @Chiel It is also possible with less changes to the indexing (see workaround 2)